# Using thymeleaf value in bootstrap alert

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

I want to use backend generated data in my html file, after validation. I'm able to do that in `jsp` but I'm having problem with `thymeleaf`. The code snippet under shows how it's working in jsp. 3rd line shows how to append `flashKind` attr into bootstrap alert class. flashKind's value can be `danger` or `success`. I'm aware of `th:appendClass` but it wont work here because it will append the value as a separate word. I need it like: `alert-success` or `alert-danger` as one word.

```
<div class="container">
    <c:if test="${not empty flashMessage}">
        <div class="alert alert-${flashKind} alert-dismissable">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          ${flashMessage}
        </div>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use literal subsitution for that:

```
<div th:class="|alert alert-${flashKind} alert-dismissable|">
```

Or you can append strings together:

```
<div th:class="alert alert-dismissable" th:classAppend="${'alert-' + flashKind}">
or
<div th:class="${'alert alert-' + flashKind + ' alert-dismissable'}">
```

There are any number of ways to do this.